# RewriteRule emty url with weblogic plug-in

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is one apache server and there are four weblogic node behind the apache server.
Clients call apache servers;  example.com/ADZ , example.com/media ,  example.com

Clients want that when they call only empty url  example.com they want to access  example.com/ADZ
Could you help me please.

This is may configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
   WebLogicCluster wls1:7003,wls1:7005,wls2:7003,wls2:7005
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /ADZ [R]

<Location /ADZ>
 SetHandler weblogic-handler
</Location>
<Location /media>
 SetHandler weblogic-handler
</Location>
```

Comment: So what is the issue? We see you have a RewriteRule here. Does it work? No? If so, what does it do, what does it not do? Are we meant to _guess_ that? Please think from the readers point of view when asking a question!

Answer (score 0):

> `when they call only empty url example.com they want to access example.com/ADZ`

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /ADZ [L,R]
```